# ubuntu 12.04 LTS: installing samba fails

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS and everything is ok with nic and accessing internet, but when I use Ubuntu Software Center to install Samba it fails;(I installed other softwares using Ubuntu Software Center and it worked just fine)
[image]

or when I use terminal to install it via terminal it says:

```
wiki@wiki-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install samba
[sudo] password for wiki: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libwbclient0 samba-common smbclient tdb-tools
Suggested packages:
  openbsd-inetd inet-superserver smbldap-tools ldb-tools ctdb cifs-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  samba tdb-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libwbclient0 samba-common smbclient
3 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 597 not upgraded.
Need to get 22.3 MB/22.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 23.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libwbclient0 i386 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libwbclient0 i386 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main smbclient i386 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main samba-common all 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main samba i386 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/libwbclient0_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/smbclient_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/samba-common_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/samba_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.6_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
wiki@wiki-VirtualBox:~$
```

please help

Comment: Maybe your internet connection is interrupted at that very moment? Have you tried to use using different mirror?

Comment: You need to run `sudo apt-get update` before installing o refresh your sources.

Comment: tnx, it worked;

Comment: Answered in comments of OP....